# Sinch Video Call get Notification for Audio Call

Tags: ios, swift, sinch

I'm getting "Incoming audio call" however the call is Video

Hint: I'm using (IOS SDK 3.10.1) SDK and [SinchService](https://github.com/sinch/SinchService-iOS).

here is the code:

```
func startVideoCall(userId: String, isPrivate: Bool) -> SINCall? {
        if let user = User.current {
            let callingId = userId
            if let callClient = self.callClient() {
                let privateString = isPrivate ? VoipCallConstants.Parameters.PrivateTrue : VoipCallConstants.Parameters.PrivateFalse
                let headers:[String: String] = [VoipCallConstants.Parameters.Private:privateString]
                let call = callClient.callUserVideo(withId: callingId, headers: headers)
                return call
            }
        }
        return nil
    }


func callClient() -> SINCallClient? {
        let appDelegate: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
        return appDelegate.sinch?.callClient()
    }

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{

    var sinch: SINService!
    var push: SINManagedPush!
}
```

and i added in SINSLazyCallClient this

```
- (id<SINCall>)callUserVideoWithId:(NSString *)userId {
    return [self callUserVideoWithId:userId headers:@{}];
}

- (id<SINCall>)callUserVideoWithId:(NSString *)userId headers:(NSDictionary *)headers {
    if (self.proxee) {
        return [self.proxee callUserVideoWithId:userId headers:headers];
    } else {
        return [[SINSFailedCall alloc] initWithUserId:userId headers:headers];
    }
}
```

here is Localization.strings

```
SIN_INCOMING_CALL = "Incoming audio call";
SIN_INCOMING_CALL_DISPLAY_NAME = "Incoming audio call from %@";
SIN_INCOMING_VIDEO_CALL = "Incoming video call";
SIN_INCOMING_VIDEO_CALL_DISPLAY_NAME = "Incoming video call from %@";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback. We looked into this and it turned out the support for `SIN_INCOMING_VIDEO_CALL` and `SIN_INCOMING_VIDEO_CALL_DISPLAY_NAME` is not implemented in our system yet. We will keep you updated once this is fixed.